# Regex for UPC-A type barcodes

Tags: regex

Given any user input, how can I validate a UPC-A type barcode using a regular expression?

Considering the following cases:

```
Input              Expected  Actual
00000000000        (X)       (Y)
000000000000       (Y)       (Y)
0000000000000      (X)       (Y)
90000000000        (X)       (Y)
900000000000       (Y)       (Y)
9000000000000      (X)       (Y)
99999999999        (X)       (X)
999999999999       (X)       (X)
9999999999999      (X)       (X)
```

I have come up with the following expression, however it does not validate the length of the input, only that it contains a single `0` as required by the spec.

```
^([1-9]*[0]+[1-9]*)$
```

How can I adjust this expression such that it will only match the marked cases, taking the overall length of the input into account?

The matched text should be 12 numbers, and must contain at least one zero.

Comment: What regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead here to assert that at least one zero is present:

```
^(?=.*0)[0-9]{12}$
```

## Demo

Comment: Ahh, never really learned to use lookahead. This seems like a much more elegant solution. Just dropped it in place and it works perfectly. Much appreciated.

Comment: @MattClark If you don't have a length requirement then what you started out with is probably the way to go.  But without a lookahead I don't see a nice way of enforcing a zero and a fixed length.